# Apache PDFBox documentation and examples

Tags: pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have done some preliminary work with itextpdf and kind of like it but probably can't use it because of the licensing requirements to purchase a corporate license and my volume just would not warrant doing that. PDFBox would appear to be another alternative but the documentation and examples seem to be pretty sparse. Perhaps my search criteria have not been well enough focused. Can anyone point me to some reasonable how tos or tutorials or documentation?

Comment: Download the source code, it has examples for everything in the example module. A few beginners example are also on https://pdfbox.apache.org , search on the page for "cookbook". You can also ask specific questions here or on the PDFBox user mailing list, but there is no "PDFBox in action" book. Note also that PDFBox is much more low level than itext.

Comment: There is an examples project part of the Pdfbox project Suite. As you are coming from iText, though, please don't expect the layouting mechanisms you might have got to know. Pdfbox is more low level. EDIT oops, I just saw @Tilman already commented like this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Will need to figure out a way to accomplish what I need.